# Is this correct way of solving this taks that relates to integral calculus

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The task says find $G'(x)$ ($G$ differentiated) if $G(x) = \int_{2x}^1f(t)\,dt.$ I have found it like this:

$$G(x) = \int_{2x}^1f(t)\,dt = G(x) = F(t)|_{2x}^1 = F(1) - F(2x) / \frac{d}{dt} = 0 -F^,(2x)\cdot 2  = -2f(2x)$$

The way they solved it in the textbook was this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HniuO.jpg

Is may way of solving this correct and if not , what have I done wrong, we both have the same result in the end

Comment: You have the exact same method as the textbook. You just didn't skip out any working.

Comment: yes but i don't know why did they do this -$\int_1^{2x}f(t)dt$

Comment: Because then it is more clear when they differentiate and have to negate the result. It is fine to just write the derivative as $-2f(2x)$ in one line of working if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

$$G(x)=\int_{2x}^{1}{f(t)\mathrm d t}=\int_{2x}^{0}{f(t)\mathrm d t}+\int_{0}^{1}{f(t)\mathrm d t}=\int_{2x}^{0}{f(t)\mathrm d t}+k=-\int_{0}^{2x}{f(t)\mathrm d t}+k,$$ for some constant $k.$

Now, differentiating, we get $G'(x)=-(2x)'×f(2x)+0=-2f(2x).$

Comment: My way is also correct right,just less work?